# Can't login to Magento 2 in Chrome?

Tags: magento2-dev-beta, admin-login, system.log

I recently installed Magento 2 in my localhost. But I can't login admin panel using chrome. (firefox it can be login). When I try to login, I'm not getting any error message. But URL changes to admin dashboard. Even though the login page remains as it is. It does not redirect to the dashboard.

And in my `system.log` I'm getting the following content. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this? What am I missing here?

NOTE: I didn't install sample data

```
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'logo' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header_schedule_block0' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header_schedule_block0' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'user' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'user' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'menu' element cannot be added as child to 'page.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.breadcrumbs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'formkey' element cannot be added as child to 'page.formkey', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'js_translate' element cannot be added as child to 'page.js.translate', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page-title' element cannot be added as child to 'main.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'messages' element cannot be added as child to 'page.messages', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' element cannot be added as child to 'page.main.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'locale.switcher' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'legal' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.loader' element cannot be added as child to 'backend.page', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.loader' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'backend.page' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'system_messages' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'notifications' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'system_messages', but their parents are different: 'notifications' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'notification_window' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header_schedule_block1' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header_schedule_block1' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'ui.global.config' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-03-17 08:15:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'ui.global.config' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'footer' and '' respectively. [] []
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a pre stable version of Magento 2: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Comment: Yes. I think it's better to close this question since many of us using the M2 stable version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have base URL without dots in domain name, like 'http://localhost' - try changing it to something with, like: 'http://magento.local'. There might be problems with serving cookies on such domains.

Comment: Yes, this has been a frequent problem. I often use 127.0.0.1 to get around it. There is something on our backlog about it as well. Putting a dot in the domain name solves the problem. Its something around scoping of cookies by domain names (I cannot remember the details just now). The result is the browser does not send the session cookie, so it thinks its a new session. (Something like that.)